# Automapper Unmapped members were found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Going nuts here...

Model:

```
public class CountryModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required (ErrorMessage = "A value is required")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "Minimum value is 4 characters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ENTITFRAMEWORK DB MODEL

```
public partial class Country
{
    public Country()
    {
        this.City = new HashSet<City>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<City> City { get; set; }
}
```

Mapper:

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Country, CountryModel>();
                cfg.CreateMap<CountryModel, Country>().ForMember(x=> x.City, opt => opt.Ignore());
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Fails on city... what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Using Automapper V7.0.1

EDIT2:

Mapping like so:

```
    public int AddCountry(CountryModel model)
    {
        var mappedC = _mapper.Map<CountryModel, Country>(model);

        int countryId = _locationManager.AddCountry(mappedC);

        return 1;
    }
```

I am mapping from countrymodel(source) to Country(destination)

EDit 3:

Error message:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the source/destination type For no matching constructor, add a no-arg
>   ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>   ===================================================================== AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be
>   mapped using the current configuration. CountryModel -> Country
>   (Destination member list) NetworkTool.Models.Location.CountryModel ->
>   NetworkTool.Data.Country (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties: City

Comment: I ran the code above, and it executed successfully. What exactly is the error it's throwing?

Comment: Are you converting from CountryModel to Country or vice versa?  All you've shown are the object classes and the configuration, but not how you are actually triggering the mapping from one class to another.

Comment: Please see edit 2

Comment: @EricDamtoft see edit 3

Comment: @ThunD3eR see https://dotnetfiddle.net/uIMioV. Possibly _mapper is a different Mapper instance than the singleton which is used by Mapper.Initialize?

Comment: I think that is exactly what's wrong...._mapper is not using the same configuration that is provided in the question....it's using AM's default convention based mapping which doesn't understand City.   Take Eric's fiddle and comment out the countrymodel->country map configuration and you will see the error there also.

Comment: @EricDamtoft Thank you for jump starting my brain! The problem was that I was following a guide (show in my answer below) on how to use automapper together with structuremap. I copies a peace of code that changed my automapper configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was following [This guide on automaper + structuremap](https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-automapper-with-structuremap-in-asp-net-web-api/)

In the default registry I had this:

```
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(profile);
        }
    });

    //Create a mapper that will be used by the DI container
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    //Register the DI interfaces with their implementation
    For<IMapperConfiguration>().Use(config);
    For<IMapper>().Use(mapper);
```

This obviosly chnaged my automapper settings.

I had to change it to:

```
var mapper = AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();

For<IMapper>().Use(mapper.CreateMapper());
```

And changed my intial mapping to :

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static MapperConfiguration Configure()
    {
        var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Country, CountryModel>();
                cfg.CreateMap<CountryModel, Country>().ForMember(x => x.City, opt => opt.Ignore());
            }
        );

        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Then my mappngs finaly worked

Answer (score 1):

You're mapping code is fine and should work fine if everything is configured properly.   I believe the issue that you are having is that while you have configured AM properly for your example, the actual mapper that is doing the work to translate from model to entity is not using your actual configuration.   Like Eric, I ran the code you provided and it works fine....unless I comment out the actual mapping in the configuration.   I think the reason you get this exception is because AM is attempting to convert using it's own convention mapping rather than your defined mapping.   AM can figure out Id and Name automatically without configuration, but fails on city.  You need to make sure that your _mapper is actually pointing to a "configured mapper".

If I run this (as you have it), the code works fine.

```
public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Country, CountryModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<CountryModel, Country>().ForMember(x => x.City, opt => opt.Ignore());
        });
    }
```

If I run this (with the mapping commented out), it will throw the unmapped exception.

```
public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Country, CountryModel>();
            //cfg.CreateMap<CountryModel, Country>().ForMember(x => x.City, opt => opt.Ignore());
        });
    }
```